# getting error java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, classcastexception

I have this function from which I am trying to extract the name from a table using a sql query.

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public String getEmpNameFromId(long Id) {
        final Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        String name = "";
        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT name from employee where id=" + Id);
        List<Object[]> list = (List<Object[]>)query.list();//Object[] objs = (Object[])query.uniqueResult()
        for (Iterator<Object[]> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Object[] e = iterator.next();
            name = (String)e[0];//case object type to another by youself...
        }
        return name;
    }
```

In my database object I am calling this function as:

```
String empName = empDao.getEmpNameFromId(data.getId());
logger.info("name"+empName);
```

The interface having function getEmpNameFromId is as:

```
public interface empDao {
    String getEmpNameFromId(long Id);
}
```

I am getting the exception as :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

Need some help here.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try this instead: `name = e[0].toString();`

Comment: Please check again where the exception occurs. It complains about an illegal cast of a instance of `String` to `Object[]` and that doesn't happen in the line, where you added your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use one column in the query, the result type of the element of list is returned as a single `Object`. Otherwise if many columns are used then result type is `Object[]` per row.

From the docs:

> ```
> public List list() throws HibernateException;
> ```
>
> Return the query results as a `List`. If the query contains
>   multiple results pre row, the results are returned in an instance of
>   `Object[]`.

Change

```
List<Object[]> list = (List<Object[]>)query.list();
```

to

```
List list = query.list();
```

Then your result should return only one row with the `String` type of the element of the `List`.

```
return (String)list.get(0);
```